# Java Selenium waiting to one ajax out of several options

Tags: java, ajax, selenium

I have a problem with selenium (java). After clicking on a button, the webpage has an ajax call which can take 10-20 seconds, and afterwards there can be several completely different results (that I can identify with By locator Separately).
For example:

```
res1:  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("id1")));
res2:  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("id2")));
res3:  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("id3")));
```

How do I program a wait that will be triggered once one of the results is displayed?

Comment: I guess that's the answer. `visibilityOfElementLocated`. Isn't it?\

Comment: If you just want to wait until the ajax is done you could do a wait.Until for this javascript to == 0 `return window.Ajax.activeRequestCount;` We have a method in .NET to do this, unfortunately I'm not sure what it would look like in java

Comment: @saifur, visibilityOfElementLocated is not good, because I don't know which of the ids will be visible when the ajax is finished